# Words in transparent PNG have jagged edges

Tags: c#, wpf, transparency

I've built an app which uses transparent PNGs to display an overlay for users to tap using WPF and C#. However, there are weird jagged edges around the words. Would this be more of a C#/WPF limitation or a Photoshop issue?

Screen resolution is 720p. App runs on win7pro.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you insert the screenshot inline?  That provider is blocked at my office.  StackOverflow will host it for you.  Also, if you can post the actual PNG, I can take a look at it.

Comment: I'm on the mobile app, not sure how I should do that :(

Comment: D'oh.  Maybe somebody else will see this and edit the post for us.

Comment: Aww :( anyway thanks in advance!

Comment: Just realized I can view it on my phone.  Duh.  Can you post the actual transparent PNG that you're hosting in your app?  It does look like it's using simple bitmask transparency instead of a full alpha channel, so without seeing the actual image, my money is on the image being the culprit.

Comment: Sure. Here goes. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz18SRNqwVSPczNmSTktNjB0eFU/preview

Comment: What kind of document is that?  The viewer on my phone won't let me save it.

Comment: It's a PNG file created by Photoshop CS5. I changed the sharing settings to allow you to see it. Do you mind if I email it to you?

Comment: I am confused, where does Photoshop come into play?　Where is the code to create the PNG? Is it using GDI+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a problem with the image itself.  I see the same fringing when viewing the image against a black background on my phone.  Make sure you compose the text over a transparent background (i.e., don't remove the background with a magic wand tool) and save with a full alpha channel (32-bit PNG).

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. Strange that I don't see it on my phone on Firefox, or on Windows' default viewer. Thanks!

Comment: It's not really noticeable when you view the image against a light background, as the fringing itself is lightly colored.  When drawing antialiased text, the edges are blended with the background, which I'm guessing was originally white or light gray.  Looks like only the exact background color was removed, so the blended edges remained.  If you compose with a transparent background and save with an alpha channel, the edges will simply have lower transparency instead of being blended, so it will look smooth over any scene.